# ASP.NET Webforms : hide console window while running .bat file

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file

I am trying to execute .bat file on my .aspx web pages
what I tried is this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Application["Loaded"] == null)
        {
            Application["Loaded"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int visits = (int)Application["Loaded"];
            visits++;
            Application["Loaded"] = visits;

            if (visits > 50)
            {
                ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
                //ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                ps.UseShellExecute = false;
                ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process P = new Process();
                P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Process.Start(@"C:\Users\percoid it\Documents\Tempremover.bat");                    
                Application["Loaded"] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did try all this method and process but I still get the pop up console window.

I am trying to remove all the temp file that has been stored in my PC and `.bat` file does remove after loading my Crystal Report more than 50 times.

The issue is if I load report more than 50 time my report does crash and after adding `.bat` file it removed the temp files stored by Crystal Report.

But the issue here is only the pop up of that batch file while executing

Comment: There are no visible console windows on a web server. You'd only get a console window if you run the web site using IIS Express on your own account. Your code shouldn't be using batch files like this at all though. What is this batch doing that can't be done in code? And why WebForms anyway?

Comment: IIS application pool accounts have no permissions outside the web app's folder too. This way a hijacked web app won't be able to access any other files on a machine. You'd have to weaken security to allow a web app to access folders on a specific user's folder

Comment: Please see my edited version that is the issue I am getting rather then that everything works fine

Comment: I already explained there are no visible consoles on a web server, so there's nothing to fix. Only a logged-on user can see console windows opened under their own account. You only see the console because you run IIS Express under your own account. If you used IIS with an app pool account you wouldn't see anything. The problem you need to fix is the CR temporary files. I suspect this must be an ancient application because nobody uses CR for several years: SSRS replaced them almost completely, and even SSRS was supplanted by Power BI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you're facing with [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) is
that you've created an instance of [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8), but haven't used it.

Try the following:

```
string exePath = @"C:\Users\percoid it\Documents\Tempremover.bat";
string arguments = null;

//create new instance
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath);
startInfo.Arguments = arguments; //arguments
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //don't create a window
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //redirect standard error
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect standard output
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //if true, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

//create new instance
using (Process p = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
{
    //subscribe to event and add event handler code
    p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            //ToDo: add desired code 
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
        }
    };

    //subscribe to event and add event handler code
    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            //ToDo: add desired code
            Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
        }
    };

    p.Start(); //start

    p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
    p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

    //waits until the process is finished before continuing
    p.WaitForExit();

}
```

**Resources**:

- [ProcessStartInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Process.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_)
- [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8)